# How to separete div blocks with the same class but diffent features

Tags: javascript, html, css

Good day!

I have a pop-up section. There are 2 div blocks in it with identical structure. The idea is to have 2 buttons (one is to edit a profile the other is to create a new card with some info) that will call this pop-up, but i need to track which one is called. The popup itself has a darker background compare to main page and a form. I have thought of a modifier ***popup__container_type_(edit/create)*** that has a ***display: none*** command so when i toggle it it the popup would appear with the right form. Most likely my logic was mistaken. I dont know how to distiguish them (div blocks) correctly.

Another problem is that closebutton seems to work for one form only.
Any help would be great!

**HTML:**

```
<section class="popup">

  <div class="popup__container popup__container_type_edit">
     <button type="button" class="popup__cancelbutton"></button>
        <form class="popup-form" name="form">
          <h2 class="popup-form__title">Header 1</h2>
          <input type="text" class="popup-form__input popup-form__input_type_name" name="name">
          <input type="text" class="popup-form__input popup-form__input_type_job" name="job">
          <button type="submit" class="popup-form__savebutton">Save</button>
        </form>
   </div>

   <div class="popup__container popup__container_type_create">
       <button type="button" class="popup__cancelbutton"></button>
       <form class="popup-form" name="form">
          <h2 class="popup-form__title">Header 2</h2>
          <input type="text" class="popup-form__input popup-form__input_type_place" placeholder="Name of the place" name="place">
          <input type="text" class="popup-form__input popup-form__input_type_imagelink" placeholder="Image link" name="imagelink">
          <button type="submit" class="popup-form__savebutton">Create</button>
       </form>
   </div>

</section>
```

**JS:**

```
let popUpSection = document.querySelector(`.popup`);
let cancelButton = popUpSection.querySelector(`.popup__cancelbutton`);

let popUpContainer = popUpSection.querySelector(`.popup__container`);
let formElement = popUpSection.querySelector(`.popup-form`);
let newInputName = popUpSection.querySelector(`.popup-form__input_type_name`);
let newInputJob = popUpSection.querySelector(`.popup-form__input_type_job`);

let inputName = document.querySelector(`.profile-info__title`);
let inputJob = document.querySelector(`.profile-info__text`);
let editButton = document.querySelector(`.profile-info__editbutton`);
let createButton = document.querySelector(`.profile__addbutton`);
//Open / close popup section

let formTogglePopUp = () => {

    if (!popUpSection.classList.contains(`popup_acitve`)){
     //Autofill
       newInputName.value = inputName.textContent;
       newInputJob.value = inputJob.textContent;
     }
    popUpSection.classList.toggle(`popup_active`);
   }
//Save input changes
function popUpFormSaved (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  
  inputName.textContent = newInputName.value;
  inputJob.textContent = newInputJob.value;

  formTogglePopUp();
}

formElement.addEventListener('submit', popUpFormSaved);

cancelButton.addEventListener('click', formTogglePopUp);

editButton.addEventListener('click', formTogglePopUp);

createButton.addEventListener(`click`, formTogglePopUp);
```

**CSS:**

```
.popup__container
{
  display: block; *by default*
}

.popup__container_type_(edit/create)
{
  display: none;
}

.popup
{
  display:none;
}

.popup__active
{
   display: flex;
}
```

Comment: Use different ids for them

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with js, set ids and use them instead of class, it's more easy.

```js
function popUpEdit() {
    document.getElementById("popUp").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("popUpEdit").style.display = "block";
}

function popUpCreate() {
    document.getElementById("popUp").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("popUpCreate").style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
#popUp, #popUpEdit, #popUpCreate {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="smt">
    Hello
    <button onclick="popUpEdit()">Edit</button>
</div>
<div class="smt">Hello
    <button onclick="popUpCreate()">Create</button>
</div>

<section id="popUp">
    <div>popUp</div>
    <div id="popUpEdit">Edit-popup</div>
    <div id="popUpCreate">Create-popup</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, however this type of code works only once. I have to reaload the page for it to work again.

Comment: You have to add the rest: Close button to hide your popup or edit/create whatever you want

Answer (score 0):

Generaly, I do that this way:

```js
const SectionPopUp = document.querySelector('section.popup')

function show(elm) 
  {
  SectionPopUp.classList.toggle('Create','Create'===elm)
  SectionPopUp.classList.toggle('Edit','Edit'===elm)
  }
```

```css
section.popup,
section.popup.Edit > div:not(.popup__container_type_edit),
section.popup.Create > div:not(.popup__container_type_create)  {
  display:none;
  }
section.popup.Edit,
section.popup.Create {
  display:block;
  }
  
/* cosmetic part, just for testing here */
section.popup > div {
  border  : 1px solid aqua;
  padding : .6em;
  margin  : 1em;
  width   : 15em;
  }
div.popup__container_type_create {
  border-color: orange !important;
  }
```

```html
<button onclick="show('Edit')"> show Edit </button>
<button onclick="show('Create')"> show Create </button>
<button onclick="show('')"> show none </button>


<section class="popup">
  <div class="popup__container popup__container_type_edit">
    pop-up edit content
  </div>
  <div class="popup__container popup__container_type_create">
    pop-up create content 
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Here is the problem, i have 2 div block and they have the same class names 'popup__container'. According to the task I cannot change it, i can only add modifiers. Though without the that class with different class names it works just fine

Comment: @TahirRuzbaev It's just a matter of names. I changed my code using your same class names